# Get AVG value for each selected row from MySQL table with 500m rows?

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

I have one table with 500 million records In MySQL 8.x. My regular query to get a certain result set is 200ms, but if I try to get an AVG value the performance drops to 30s+.

Structure:

```
KW_ID | DATE | SERP | MERCHANT_ID | ARTICLE_ID

-- auto-generated definition
create table merchants_keyword_serps
(
    KW_ID       mediumint unsigned                        null,
    MERCHANT_ID tinyint unsigned                          null,
    ARTICLE_ID  char(10)                                  null,
    SERP        tinyint unsigned                          null,
    DATE        date                                      null,
    constraint `unique`
        unique (MERCHANT_ID, ARTICLE_ID, KW_ID, DATE),
    constraint fk_serps_kwd_t
        foreign key (MERCHANT_ID, ARTICLE_ID) references merchants_product_catalog (MERCHANT_ID, ARTICLE_ID)
            on delete cascade,
    constraint keywords
        foreign key (KW_ID) references merchants_keywords (ID)
            on delete cascade
);

create index merchants_keyword_serps_SERP_index
    on merchants_keyword_serps (SERP);

create index mks_date
    on merchants_keyword_serps (DATE);
```

Goal, get SERP for 20220122 and MERCHANT_ID = 2:

```
select
       mcs.SERP
FROM merchants_keyword_serps mcs
WHERE date = 20220120
AND mcs.MERCHANT_ID = 2;
```

Now do also get the AVG SERP for all shops in addition:

```
select
       mcs.SERP,
       (
        SELECT AVG(SERP)
           FROM merchants_keyword_serps mcs2
           WHERE mcs2.date = 20220120
           AND mcs2.KW_ID = mcs.KW_ID
           AND mcs2.ARTICLE_ID = mcs.ARTICLE_ID) AS SERP_AVG
from  merchants_keyword_serps mcs
WHERE
    date = 20220120
    AND mcs.MERCHANT_ID = 2;
```

The expected result would be an additional column with the average SERP value for all shops with the same KW_ID, DATE, ARTICLE_ID.

Is there a way to speed that up with a different approach? The indexes are all set OK I believe since the standard query runs perfectly fast in unter 200ms.

Comment: The mistake is probably in "Indexes are set on all relevant columns".  Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for each table.

Answer (score 0):

Where does `KW_ID` come from?  Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE merchants_keyword_serps`.

Using `20220120` for a date is asking for trouble.  (I don't see any problem *yet*.)

Add these:

```
INDEX(merchant_id, date)
INDEX(kw_id, article_id, date, serp)
```

and Drop these since they will be redundant:

```
INDEX(merchant_id)
INDEX(kw_id)
```

Comment: KW_ID is in the same table (forgot to point out), I added the DDL to the question including indexes and FK.

Comment: @merlin - Thanks.  My suggestions stand.

Comment: Would it help to refactor the dependent subquery to a LEFT JOINed independent subquery?

Comment: @O.Jones - Maybe.  But I suspect there is an un-specified correlation on `date`.  Merlin should try it.  The Optimizer is smart enough to switch between 'correlated subquery', `LEFT JOIN`, `EXISTs`, and `IN(SELECT..)` -- but I have not figured out when it might or might not do so.  Without the test on `mcs2.date`, I would be very tempted to do a `JOIN` -- hoping to compute all the AVGs at once, then JOIN to the other table.